# how can I append dynamic div using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to create some dynamic div on each click of a button. If there is already such div at the top, the next such div will show below all of them but if there is none, this new div will start from top.

Also, after five seconds of adding, each div should vanish itself and all divs below this vanishing div should come upwards?

Here is my code:

```
 $("body").append("<div style='position:
 absolute;top:0;right:0'     
 class='dynamic alert-danger'>something wrong!!!!</div>");
setTimeout(function() {
 $('.dynamic').fadeOut('fast');
 }, 5000);
```

Comment: And whats wrong with the code? What exactly inst working?

Comment: Er... Sorry your English isn't clear. Would you like to rephrase or explain in a different way?

Comment: Why does the code you posted not working? Post a fiddle/plnk please.

Comment: two problems of that code.the first one is the divs are not showing sequentially it replaces the previous one and after 5 seconds all the div removes

Answer (score 1):

```js
var bubbleCounter = 0;
$("#add-bubble").on("click", function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var counter = bubbleCounter + 1;
  var htmlString = '<div class="bubbles" id="bubble-'+counter+'">'+counter+'</div>';
  $("#bubbles-container").append( htmlString );
  setTimeout(function(){
    $("#bubble-"+counter).remove();
  }, 3000 );
  bubbleCounter = counter;
});//#add-bubble click()
```

```css
body{
  position: relative;
}
#bubbles-container{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100px;
}
#bubbles-container .bubbles{
  color: #fff;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: orange;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="bubbles-container"></div>
<button id="add-bubble">Add bubble</button>
```

Comment: thank's a lot Mohit bro exacty same what I'm wanting.